# Fetching content from webhook wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs, webhooks

I am developing a web app which, among other things, enables users to write a small text, have it saved, and automatically posted to their wordpress blog.

I am wondering about Wordpress as my platform, which has already some features that I need.

Wordpress has webhooks that sent notifications to other websites. I would like to know if it is possible to send content [short text] with the notifications and display it as a post in the final wordpress blog.

Other suggestions are also welcome.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You could just post via email http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Writing_Screen#Post_via_e-mail  have the web app send an email to the corresponding wordpress email that is setup for that blog

Comment: Thank you for the help. It opened a new opportunity for my app.

Comment: Just to be complete. The solution that we found was to send the data from our application to Wordpress using email. So, we set up an email account exclusively for this, and we used some pluggins that fetch content from emails and post them as a blog post. In this way we could get what we want from the db and post at specific times using cron jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking if you can use Wordpress as the base of your new web app, and use the webhook functionality in Wordpress to send data to other Wordpress blogs.

If this is correct, you can use webhooks to send data from Wordpress to somewhere else.  Wordpress allows you to send webhooks when a new post is created, when a new comment is made or when a new page is created.

Webhooks are outbound-only and they are one-sided, that is to say that you can get Wordpress to send a webhook with the content you want, but you have to have something on the other side to catch the incoming data.  That thing must understand what Wordpress webhook data looks like and how to call the Wordpress API on the receiving side.

Wordpress does not understand how to receive webhooks, even if they are sent by another Wordpress site.

You could accomplish what you want by writing a Wordpress plugin that could call the other Wordpress via api.  The call you would want is here:

[Wordpress API call to create a post](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1/post/sites/%24site/posts/new/)

Unfortunately, there are very few options in terms of handling incoming webhooks apart from writing custom code to catch the webhook and do something with it.  The company I work for created something to do things like this, but it's still in private beta. (see my profile if you are interested)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will research more about my options and whatever solution I find I will share here.